# USB ports not working - how diagnose problem?

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb

USB ports suddenly not working after computer wouldn't boot properly, for hours.

Could only turn off by unplugging. I left it off overnight, but when I turned back on, it can't see USB thumb drives.

How do I find the problem & fix it?

---

edit:
This puter has seen a number of power outages, as well as accumulating problems over time, being updated, upgraded, & many diff programs installed. No idea what one, or more than one recent installs would, if, did it.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0111 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card Reader
```

---

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Do you see any prob in there?

---

I plugged in a thumb drive in USB port & did

```
$ dmesg | tail
[ 5352.260166] usb 2-6: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[ 5352.544120] usb 2-6: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[ 5352.824104] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci_hcd
[ 5353.004050] usb 2-6: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[ 5353.288057] usb 2-6: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[ 5353.568076] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ohci_hcd
[ 5353.976041] usb 2-6: device not accepting address 5, error -62
[ 5354.152037] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ohci_hcd
[ 5354.560037] usb 2-6: device not accepting address 6, error -62
[ 5354.560058] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 6
```

---

Also checked for "udev" in Ubuntu Software Center. It was already installed.

Could that have been corrupted or something, so the USB ports don't work properly?

Comment: [edit] in the output of the `lsusb` and `xinput` commands.

Comment: Any idea what caused the problem (power cuts, recently installed stuff, etc)?

Comment: See above edit.

Comment: See also another question I posted that is related:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/693223/scanner-not-working-in-conjunction-with-usb-ports-not-working-how-diag-fix